# My div's are not showing?

Tags: html, css

Hi can you please help me how to fix this? my div's are not showing and when I inspect it is there but it is not showing the whole content of it.

Here is my div code

```
<div id="men_product"  style="">
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
                  <div class="transbox">
                    <img src="images/9img.jpg">
                  </div> <!-- /transbox -->
                </div> <!-- /col-md-6 -->
                <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
                     <div class="carousel slide" id="carouselExampleControls4" data-ride="carousel">
                        <div class="text-md-right">
                          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls4" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                          </a>
                          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls4" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden= "true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                          </a>
                        </div> <!-- /carousel-button -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                          <div class="carousel-item">
                             <div class="row">
                                 <div class="col-md-3">
                                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                    <img src="images/3img.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;">
                                    <div class="text_box">
                                          <h4 class="hidedesktop">Christmas Clothes</h4>
                                    <div>
                                         <span class="price pull-left"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&pound;</span>300.00</span></span>
                                    </div>                                                                                        
                                    </div>
                                  </a>
                                    <a href="" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="352" data-product_sku="" aria-label="Add &ldquo;Christmas Clothes&rdquo; to your cart" rel="nofollow">Add to cart</a>   
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-md-3">
                                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                    <img src="images/3img.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;">
                                    <div class="text_box">
                                          <h4 class="hidedesktop">Christmas Clothes</h4>
                                    <div>
                                         <span class="price pull-left"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&pound;</span>300.00</span></span>
                                    </div>                                                                                        
                                    </div>
                                  </a>
                                    <a href="" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="352" data-product_sku="" aria-label="Add &ldquo;Christmas Clothes&rdquo; to your cart" rel="nofollow">Add to cart</a>   
                                 </div>                                   
                              </div><!-- END ROW -->
                            </div> <!-- /item -->

                            <div class="carousel-item">
                             <div class="row">
                                 <div class="col-md-3">
                                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                    <img src="images/3img.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;">
                                    <div class="text_box">
                                          <h4 class="hidedesktop">Christmas Clothes</h4>
                                    <div>
                                         <span class="price pull-left"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&pound;</span>300.00</span></span>
                                    </div>                                                                                        
                                    </div>
                                  </a>
                                    <a href="" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="352" data-product_sku="" aria-label="Add &ldquo;Christmas Clothes&rdquo; to your cart" rel="nofollow">Add to cart</a>   
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-md-3">
                                  <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                    <img src="images/3img.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;">
                                    <div class="text_box">
                                          <h4 class="hidedesktop">Christmas Clothes</h4>
                                    <div>
                                         <span class="price pull-left"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&pound;</span>300.00</span></span>
                                    </div>                                                                                        
                                    </div>
                                  </a>
                                    <a href="" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="352">Add to cart</a>   
                                 </div>                                   
                              </div><!-- END ROW -->
                            </div> <!-- /item -->

                        </div> <!-- /carousel-inner -->
                      </div> <!-- /carousel -->

                </div> <!-- /col-sm-6 -->
              </div> <!-- /row -->
            </div> <!-- /container -->

     </div> <!-- /col-md-12 -->
   </div> <!-- /row -->
 </div> <!-- /men-container -->
```

Here is the screenshot of my div that I want to show but it's not showing anything 
  [image: here is the screenshot of my div that I want to show]

I don't know why my div are not showing? can you please help me!!  I've been stuck with this code for days already huhu

Comment: Check its opacity? Btw you should share whole codes including css or you would get downvoted

Comment: it's not in the css tho plus the css that im  using is the default bootstrap css so I didn't really touch the css part tho @Chaska

Comment: There are so many reasons to cause this problem so it's quite difficult to get help if you cannot provide related css code. At least you can attach css code in console.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be missing one closing div tag. There are 4 opening divs before class="container", and only 3 closing. I thinking your main wrapping div (id="men_product") isn't being closed so that's why it's not displaying. Or perhaps, the last div just wasn't included when you copied the code?